# Why is probit working in MCMCpack, but not logit?

Tags: r, bayesian

I am trying to model the binary outcome "SECONDARY.LEVEL" as a function of the other three variables in [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/MCMC.csv) dataset. I am using the `MCMCpack` package for Bayesian modeling. Could someone please explain why `MCMCprobit()` works, but not `MCMClogit()`? Code and first few lines of output are given below.

```
#Read in data
df = read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1791181/MCMC.csv")
```

Probit works:

```
mcmc.probit = MCMCprobit(SECONDARY.LEVEL ~ AGE + SEX + as.factor(DISTRICT), mcmc=1000, data=df)
head(summary(mcmc.probit)$statistics, n=15)
                              Mean          SD     Naive SE Time-series SE
(Intercept)            0.150093347 0.109792702 0.0034719501   0.0059589451
AGE                   -0.035112684 0.005551112 0.0001755416   0.0003118349
SEXMale                0.207912526 0.026288448 0.0008313137   0.0011590922
as.factor(DISTRICT)2   0.004684505 0.068300292 0.0021598449   0.0028876137
as.factor(DISTRICT)3   0.147462569 0.077003268 0.0024350571   0.0036086218
as.factor(DISTRICT)4   0.056207898 0.070746208 0.0022371915   0.0030940116
as.factor(DISTRICT)5   0.262208868 0.074049641 0.0023416553   0.0035314500
as.factor(DISTRICT)6   0.167194019 0.076774267 0.0024278155   0.0037526433
as.factor(DISTRICT)7  -0.030666654 0.079221987 0.0025052192   0.0045243228
as.factor(DISTRICT)8   0.256155556 0.086851907 0.0027464985   0.0043024813
as.factor(DISTRICT)9   0.220563392 0.081925283 0.0025907049   0.0036374888
as.factor(DISTRICT)10  0.048681988 0.084193610 0.0026624357   0.0037311155
as.factor(DISTRICT)11  0.046235838 0.077788116 0.0024598762   0.0041413425
as.factor(DISTRICT)12  0.055248182 0.084691712 0.0026781871   0.0039077209
as.factor(DISTRICT)13  0.180067061 0.077430509 0.0024485677   0.0035813944
```

But not logit:

```
mcmc.logit = MCMClogit(SECONDARY.LEVEL ~ AGE + SEX + as.factor(DISTRICT), mcmc=1000, data=df)
head(summary(mcmc.logit)$statistics, n=15)
                             Mean SD Naive SE Time-series SE
(Intercept)            0.22304927  0        0              0
AGE                   -0.05566763  0        0              0
SEXMale                0.33312032  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)2   0.01497950  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)3   0.24880013  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)4   0.09670442  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)5   0.42470223  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)6   0.27617894  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)7  -0.03446564  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)8   0.41404924  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)9   0.35816907  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)10  0.08551302  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)11  0.07437629  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)12  0.09701028  0        0              0
as.factor(DISTRICT)13  0.29723229  0        0              0
```